# Unable to load UTF-8 JSON data with marshmallow

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, utf-8, marshmallow

I'm trying to use marshmallow to verify posted JSON data to my app. I post using Jquery like this:

```
var testdata = { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/v1/monitors",
    data: JSON.stringify(testdata),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg){alert(errMsg);}
});
```

On the server side I have a python app on Google App Engine with a schema like:

```
class TestSchema(Schema):
    field1 = fields.Str()
    field2 = fields.Str()
```

And a handler like:

```
def post(self):
    schema = TestSchema()
    result = schema.load(self.request.body)
    logging.error(result)
```

In the log I constantly get:

```
UnmarshalResult(data={}, errors={u'_schema': [u'Invalid input type.']})
```

But if I replace this line:

```
result = schema.load(self.request.body)
```

With this:

```
result = schema.load('{ "field1": u"value1", "field2": u"value2" }')
```

It works just fine, but I don't want to post unicode I want to use UTF-8. How can I get it to take the UTF-8 posted data and load it?

Comment: `'{ "field1": u"value1"}'` is not valid JSON. Are you sure the `schema.load()` method is meant to parse JSON?

Comment: The u infront of a string just means that it's unicode in Python. As far as I can tell it only accepts unicode encoding of the value strings. If we look at the marshmellow example from the documentation it looks like this:

    user_data = {
        'created_at': '2014-08-11T05:26:03.869245',
        'email': u'ken@yahoo.com',
        'name': u'Ken'
    }
    schema = UserSchema()
    result = schema.load(user_data)

Comment: I know what the `u` prefix in Python string literals means. But that doesn't hold for JSON strings, they never have something like that. JSON objects and Python dictionary literals do look similar, but they don't have the same syntax. So if you feed JSON to a function that expects Python literals or vice versa, things might not go as expected.

Comment: In short: if the client sends JSON, use a function that handles JSON, and not something else. Depending on your framework, the `self.request` object might even have an attribute `.json` which already holds the parsed JSON data (converted to Python types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a missing s!

The load JSON in marshmallow you need to use the .loads() and not the .load() function.

Thank you for all your efforts to help!